# Добавление колонок в DataGridVew

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Добрый день! 
Мне нужно вывести в DataGridView колонки с именами субъектов (класс Subject) из коллекции subjects, но при этом присвоить колонке в поле Tag идентификатор субъекта. 
 Вроде делаю все правильно, но в DataGridView не отображаются колонки:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < subjects.Count; i++)
            {
                var column = new DataGridViewColumn();
                column.Name = "Col" + i;
                column.HeaderText = subjects[i].Name;
                column.Tag = subjects[i].SubjectID;

                dgvJournal.Columns.Add(column);
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого отображается только первая колонка и все.

Если указывать имя колонки и текст в ручную, то все нормально работает:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < subjects.Count; i++)
            {
                dgvJournal.Columns.Add("Col" + i, subjects[i].Name);
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но так я не могу задать значение Tag у колонки.

Comment: Сделать вообще что хотите?

Comment: Отобразить в заголовках колонок содержимое коллекции subjects

Comment: Т.е у вас каждый столбец это экземпляр `Subjects`, а строки его свойства?

Comment: Нет, строки будут заполнены иначе, вопрос не про них. 
Я добавил в вопрос скрины, возможно станет яснее.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Взял форму, бросил на нее dataGridView1 и вставил Ваш код (с небольшими упрощениями в конструктор формы:

```
public Form1()  
{ InitializeComponent();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();

            column.Name = "Col" + i.ToString();
            column.HeaderText = "HeaderText_"+i.ToString();
            column.Tag = i;

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
        }

    }
```

`На строке`dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);`получил`Exception`о том, что`CellTemplate == null` для добавляемой колонки.

После этого я ручками в дизайнере добавил колонку с настройками по умолчанию и изменил конструктор:

```
        public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn(dataGridView1.Columns[0].CellTemplate);

            column.Name = "Col" + i.ToString();
            column.HeaderText = "HeaderText_"+i.ToString();
            column.Tag = i;

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);
        }

    }

Все заработало.
```

Вердикт - Вы неверно конструируете добавляемые колонки

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема было именно в этом, правда я не знаю почему у меня Exception не сгенерировался, иначе я бы сразу понял. Спасибо!

Comment: Очень рад, что мой ответ помог